# MSI. Run installed application on uninstalling a softwtware

Tags: windows-installer

Is there any way to run the installed application with an argument on uninstalling the software? E.g.: **[INSTALLDIR]\xxx.exe -uninstall**
I have a table for MSI. As far as I see, I must add a data into tables or create a custom script... but I cannot find any simple example...

Comment: How do you generate the MSI file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a [custom action](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL). The linked example can help you, all you need to do is to modify it so it launches your executable as desired.

Comment: Orca is a useful tool. Thank you for the link!

Comment: A more advanced one, and also free, is SuperOrca. http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html